# Build System for .NET with a Make/Rake-like syntax?

Tags: syntax, msbuild, build

A Build system with .NET devs as its Primary Target Audience that is does *not* have an XML-only Syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- [Boo build system](http://www.google.com/search?q=boo-build-system) (uses Boo)
- [Phantom](http://github.com/JeremySkinner/Phantom) (another one that uses Boo)
- [PSake](https://github.com/psake/psake) (uses PowerShell)
- [FAKE](https://github.com/forki/FAKE) (uses F#)

Comment: I recommend the Boo build system (Boobs). It's closest thing to Rake.

Answer (score 3):

[FluentBuild](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-build/)

There is also [UppercuT](http://code.google.com/p/uppercut/) - which uses conventions to do the building, so it is not necessary to look at that XML syntax.

Comment: +1 for FluentBuild. I hope this gets more updates in the future. Looks like a very interesting project.

Answer (score 1):

I use actual Ruby Rake, just invoke the power of msbuild through your Rake script.

It's quite simple and much better than the XML alternatives in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Check out rake-dotnet too: 
http://github.com/petemounce/rake-dotnet

I'm just about to give this a go!

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely try **NUBuild**.

I am a developer and I uses it on a regular basis and I work with around 75 projects that I need to build with every code change/release. It has saved me huge amount of time by allowing me to find build failures locally and lot earlier in the development cycle and not after I have checked in my code.

NUBuild is extremely fast, easy to setup (you do it only once) and gives you the power of a complete build server at your fingertip by letting you do 'local builds'. You do not have to write 'dense' xml scripts. There is only one simple configuration file you need to create while setting it up (Refer the user guide).  It also has lots of other advance features and functionalities. You can find more detail on the project site (on codeplex):

http://nubuild.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

[nRake](http://wiki.github.com/jcrisp/nRake/) is the way to utilize Rake itself